# building pjSIP for Android on Linux OS creates no .so files

Tags: android, linux, pjsip

I tried to implement pjSIP in my Android project following the [getting started](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) guide on their official page. I am on a Linux OS.

I installed the Android NDK with success and finished the building of pjSIP 
using this code:

```
$ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
$ export ANDROID_NDK_ROOT=/path_to_android_ndk_dir 
$ ./configure-android
$ make dep && make clean && make
```

This finished with success too. But it appears that there are no .jar or .so files to include to my android project. Is there something wrong with the getting started guide or am I missing something?

Comment: From the project directory, try `find . -name "*.so"` and see if you get anything.  If not, where there any errors produced during the build process?  That is a non-standard usage of the NDK, so it could easily break if it made unsafe assumptions based on details of an old NDK version which have since changed.  Did the instruction say to point it at the plain NDK install, or at a "stand alone toolchain" exported by the NDK?

Comment: I couldn't find any .so files, even with the regex-search. It appears that they haven't been created, but I had no errors during the compilation either. I pointed at the NDK directly, not on the toolchain-subfolder. But indeed, I downloaded the r10b NDK, while the getting started guide says that it requires at least r8b. Perhaps you are right and there have been significant changes to the NDK.

Comment: You should try to figure out what it is doing - is the normal build output suppressed somehow?  Are any .o files created?  If desperate you can see if introducing an intentional error or equivalent pragma into a source file produces output.

Answer (score 0):

**modify:**

```
./configure-android --enable-shared
```